# stacklesssocket affects other socket based module

Tags: network-programming, couchbase, python-stackless

I have a project using Stackless Python with stacklesssocket.py. I recently decided that I wanted to add Couchbase to my project to server as my database back-end. I did this following the instructions from the ([Couchbase site](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-python-1.0/couchbase-sdk-python-getting-started-installation.html)). However it does not seem to be compatible with my project, and with further investigation is seemed to be a clash with the stacklesssocket.

It would have been overly complex to show the source for my project, but I distilled the code down to a case that exactly reproduces the error I am getting:

```
import couchbase

# Monkeypatch in the 'stacklesssocket' module, so we get blocking sockets
# which are Stackless compatible.  This example code will avoid any use of
# the Stackless sockets except through normal socket usage.
import stacklesssocket
stacklesssocket.install()
import socket

# connect to a couchbase server
cb = couchbase.Server('localhost:8091', username='username', password='password')

# use default bucket
default_bucket = cb['default']

# fetch a key with a function
print 'test = ' + str(default_bucket.get('test'))
```

As you can see, I am adding the stacklesssocket and then attempting to connect to the Couchbase server The symptom is this stack trace below. I'm not sure exactly what the stacklesssocket does, but I know it replaces (or enhances) the functionality of a normal python socket. So it looks like Couchbase is using a socket and its not behaving as it expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mark/Programming/MarkTestSite/server/src/dbteststackless.py", line 12, in <module>
    cb = couchbase.Server('localhost:8091', username='username', password='password')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/couchbase/client.py", line 50, in __init__
    config = ServerHelper.parse_server_config(server_config_uri, username, password)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/couchbase/client.py", line 334, in parse_server_config
    response = urlopener.open(uri)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 344, in open_http
    h.endheaders()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 904, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 776, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 735, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 716, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 514, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

To prove that Couchbase does ordinarily work for me (always a good sanity check), here is code that works. I simply removed the code to import the stacklesssocket:

```
import couchbase

# connect to a couchbase server
cb = couchbase.Server('localhost:8091', username='username', password='password')

# use default bucket
default_bucket = cb['default']

# fetch a key with a function
print 'test = ' + str(default_bucket.get('test'))
```

Which worked as expected and generated the following output:

```
test = (0, 5, 'hello world')
```

I am using stackless python 2.6.5. Is there a work around for this that I can use? Or is the Couchbase module just plain and simply incompatible with stacklesssocket? I really want to continue to use stackless python and the stacklesssocket because my project is a network server with many concurrent connections. I appreciate any thoughts people have.

Comment: It appears that the stacklesssocket code is replacing the socket code in such a way that is preventing Couchbase module from working. If this is a solution you would like to continue with you might consider contacting Couchbase to see if there is something they can do to make their module compatible. At the very least making them aware of the conflict is a good idea.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll let them know.